# How to extend a class's functionality?

Tags: c#

This is a simple concept that I haven't had trouble with before, so help is deeply appreciated.

```
public partial class Player
{
    public string Name
    { get; private set; }

    public int Id
    { get; private set; }
}

public partial class ExtendedPlayer : Player
{
    public string Color = "";
}

public class MainProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Player p = new Player();

        // The following creates a null object "ep":
        ExtendedPlayer ep = p as ExtendedPlayer;

        // For proof, NullReferenceException is thrown here:
        ep.Color = "red";
    }
}
```

A few of the other articles I read on SO resort to creating `ep` and then manually assigning all the values of `p` to it.  This is not possible, for `Player` is only readable.

Another solution I've read is to make `Player` into an `interface`, but I can't do that either because there are Player objects.

P.S. In my situation, `Player` is actually part of a library.  I created the library, so I can change its properties, but I do not want the properties to be editable.  I can, however change the fact it is partial, if that is creating a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add functionality/behavior to a class, you should look into the decorator pattern. The implementation of the ExtendedPlayer would be something like this:

```
public interface IPlayer
{
  string Name {get;}
  string Id {get;}
}

public class Player: IPlayer
{
    public string Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    Player (string name, string id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class ExtendedPlayer: IPlayer
{
    private IPlayer  _player;
    public string Id {get { return _player.Id; }}
    public string Name {get { return _player.Name + ", " + Color; }}
    public string Color{ {get;set;}
    Player (IPlayer player, string color)
    {
        _player = player;
        Color = color;
    }
}

IPlayer player = new Player("12", "Video player");
player = new ExtendedPlayer(player, "red");
Console.WriteLine(player.Id);                      // prints 12
Console.WriteLine(player.Name);                    // prints Video player, red
Console.WriteLine(((ExtendedPlayer)player).Color); // prints red
```

Comment: I think the decorator pattern is more useful when you're sticking to the same public members for all the decorating classes. Otherwise, as your code demonstrates, you end up having to cast, and don't get a hell of a lot of benefit. In this situation I don't know why you wouldn't just do normal inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure what of the intent of the original code, and why regular inherentance doesn't suffice. I agree, the decorator pattern usually uses an unchanged interface, that's why I added it.

But assuming that the Player's properties setters need top be private, and and that ExtendedPlayer needs to replace the Original player, a wrapper-like scenario is often best. Maybe line two should be: ExtendedPlayer extendedPlayer = new ExtendedPlayer(player, "red")

Comment: regular inheritance doesn't suffice because it is impossible to set the properties of the inherited class

Answer (score 3):

You can create a protected constructor of `Player` that initializes the values:

```
public class Player {
    // other stuff same as in your example...

    protected Player(string name, int id) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public class ExtendedPlayer : Player {
    public ExtendedPlayer(Player p) : base(p.Name, p.Id) { }
}

// in your Main method, you can create an ExtendedPlayer from a Player like so:

Player p = new Player();

ExtendedPlayer e = new ExtendedPlayer(p);
```

One thing: the `as` operator does not convert objects from one type to another. Rather, it attempts to cast the value of one variable to a different type. The types must be compatible. You can't cast any type to any other type. You can read about casting here and elsewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx.

Another thing: you'll need some way of initializing the fields in your `Player` class. As it is now, the values will be the default (null for the string and 0 for the int). Perhaps you have a lot more code that we don't see, so this may not be a problem. However, note that the mechanism by which a player is initialized is relevant to how a derived class would initialize the fields belonging to the base class `Player` (as in my code above).

The question you need to ask yourself is why you want to convert a `Player` into an `ExtendedPlayer`. Why not just create the `ExtendedPlayer` in the first place? I think your model may not be well-thought out, so spend some time thinking about what you're actually trying to do in converting a `Player` into an `ExtendedPlayer` and maybe this problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upcast from player to ExtendedPlayer.  It looks like you are using c# - is so take a look at extension methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

I'm not entirely clear on why you just aren't creating a ExtendedPlayer rather than Player type in main. ExtendedPlayer derives from Player so you can't convert a Player to ExtendedPlayer but you can convert an ExtendedPlayer to Player.

Comment: Downcast**. Its confusing - but the terms come from a class diagram where the base class is on top and derived classes are below. So, downcasting is actually what you mean.. since its downward. Slight clarification :)

Comment: Why extension methods?

Comment: Tx Simon - I never can keep those straight.